# Can velocity be negative?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, conventions, coordinate-systems, speed

In free fall I use the formula V=g*t and g is negative(-9.8m/s^2). It gives me negative.

Comment: Understanding what positive and negative means in physics is pretty basic. The answer given to you is correct, and hopefully you will understand and acknowledge it. If it is not clear to you I suggest you read slowly and carefully the first couple of chapters of your physics book, and try to understand that plus or minus has meaning. For quantities with respect to a coordinate frame of reference, it means one side or other other, up or down, in or out, etc. for more abstract quantities like energy it may mean whether it is gained or lost. Read up and think about the issue before asking

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It just means that the velocity is in a direction opposite the direction of your reference frame. If you make "down = positive" then $g$ would be positive, and so would the velocity.